# How to specify the architecture/platform for a channel for a global pixi install?

Tags: conda, apple-m1, package-managers, pixi-package-manager

I'm trying to globally install a `bioconda/osx-64` package on my ARM based mac using [`pixi`](https://github.com/prefix-dev/pixi)

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```bash
$ pixi global install nextclade -c bioconda
  × Cannot solve the request because of: No candidates were found for nextclade *.
  │
```

I've tried adding `--platform osx-64` which works for `mamba`, but this doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

As of v0.15.1 (Feb 2024) it is not possible to globally install packages for a different architecture, even if Rosetta is enabled.

See [tracking issue](https://github.com/prefix-dev/pixi/issues/872).